# Why does shinyjs::reset clobber subsequent updateTextInput commands?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

The new `name` value is not getting set after the reset when "Fill example name" is hit

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    shinyjs::inlineCSS(list(.big = "font-size: 2em")),
    div(id = "myapp",
        h2("shinyjs demo"),
        checkboxInput("big", "Bigger text", FALSE),
        textInput("name", "Name", ""),
        a(id = "toggleAdvanced", "Show/hide advanced info", href = "#"),
        shinyjs::hidden(
          div(id = "advanced",
              numericInput("age", "Age", 30),
              textInput("company", "Company", "")
          )
        ),
        p("Timestamp: ",
          span(id = "time", date()),
          a(id = "update", "Update", href = "#")
        ),
        actionButton("submit", "Submit"),
        actionButton("reset", "Reset form"),
        actionButton("example", "Fill example name")
    )
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observe({
      shinyjs::toggleState("submit", !is.null(input$name) && input$name != "")
    })

    shinyjs::onclick("toggleAdvanced",
                     shinyjs::toggle(id = "advanced", anim = TRUE))

    shinyjs::onclick("update", shinyjs::html("time", date()))

    observe({
      shinyjs::toggleClass("myapp", "big", input$big)
    })

    observeEvent(input$submit, {
      shinyjs::alert("Thank you!")
    })

    observeEvent(input$reset, {
      shinyjs::reset("myapp")
    })

    observeEvent(input$example, {
      shinyjs::reset("myapp")
      shiny::updateTextInput(session, "name", value = "Joe Schmoe")
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: I think the problem is the ```shinyjs::reset("myapp")```. It will work if you remove it ```observeEvent(input$example, {shiny::updateTextInput(session, "name", value = "Joe Schmoe")})```

Comment: i need to reset the other form elements, then load the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, that `shinyjs::reset` and `updateTextInput` are firing in the same [reactive cycle](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/execution-scheduling.html).

We can exclude input$name from the reset:

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    shinyjs::inlineCSS(list(.big = "font-size: 2em")),
    div(id = "myapp",
        h2("shinyjs demo"),
        checkboxInput("big", "Bigger text", FALSE),
        textInput("name", "Name", ""),
        a(id = "toggleAdvanced", "Show/hide advanced info", href = "#"),
        shinyjs::hidden(
          div(id = "advanced",
              numericInput("age", "Age", 30),
              textInput("company", "Company", "")
          )
        ),
        p("Timestamp: ",
          span(id = "time", date()),
          a(id = "update", "Update", href = "#")
        ),
        actionButton("submit", "Submit"),
        actionButton("reset", "Reset form"),
        actionButton("example", "Fill example name")
    )
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observe({
      shinyjs::toggleState("submit", !is.null(input$name) && input$name != "")
    })
    
    shinyjs::onclick("toggleAdvanced",
                     shinyjs::toggle(id = "advanced", anim = TRUE))
    
    shinyjs::onclick("update", shinyjs::html("time", date()))
    
    observe({
      shinyjs::toggleClass("myapp", "big", input$big)
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$submit, {
      shinyjs::alert("Thank you!")
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$reset, {
      shinyjs::reset("myapp")
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$example, {
      lapply(setdiff(names(input), "name"), function(x){shinyjs::reset(x)})
      shiny::updateTextInput(session, "name", value = "Joe Schmoe")
    })
  }
)
```